# No converter found for return value of type: class org.json.JSONArray

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-restcontroller

I want to return a JSONArray(org.json.jar) object from spring controller method, this is my java spring controller :

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

@RestController
public class BICOntroller{

@RequestMapping(value="/getStatus", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<JSONArray> getStatus() throws JSONException{
      ResponseEntity<JSONArray> response = null;
      JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();

      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
      //process data
      arr.put(obj);

      response = new ResponseEntity<JSONArray>(arr, HttpStatus.OK);
      return response;
  }

}
```

Angular js call :

```
            $http({
                url: 'getStatus',
                method: 'GET',
                responseType: 'json'
            }).then(function(response){
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            }, function(error){
                console.log(error);
                return error;
            });
```

This gives 500 error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class org.json.JSONArray
```

I have included `jackson-core-2.7.5.jar` and `jackson-databind-2.7.5.jar` in the class path.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `arr` that you are trying to send in response?

Comment: i added that variable in question.

Comment: I don't understand why you specify `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` there. It will get converted to correct JSON type based on what you return (A collection or simple Object) from the handler method in controller.

Comment: It works if i create java objects, but i wanted to avoid creating more classes, anyways.. i converted JSONArray to List and JSONObject to Map to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

Adding the dependencies did not work for me. What did work is **converting the JSONArray to String**. 
FYI I am using Spring Boot Application and was trying to return a JSONArray.

Answer (score 2):

**Apart** from adding dependencies, you may need this.

If you are **not** using spring boot, update your spring `xxx-servlet.xml` with **message converters for JSON**.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
     <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

**if you are using spring boot**, adding dependencies in pom.xml alone will suffice.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```